# Check whether O365 product license is enabled

Tags: powershell, office365

I need to configure O365 licences via PowerShell which I have no problem with but would like to add an if statement before this to check whether the product is enabled before modifying otherwise it fails.

Currently I have the following to modify (enable all services) the already enabled Office 365 Enterprise E3 product:

```
$O365EntE3 = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId tenent:ENTERPRISEPACK

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $Upn -LicenseOptions $O365EntE3
```

What would I need to run to check whether the tenent:ENTERPRISEPACK is enabled first?

Cheers
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether Enterprise pack is there,you can use the below snippet (Tested in powershell v5):

```
$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn 
if($user.Licenses.AccountSku.SkuPartNumber -contains 'Enterprisepack'){
    write-output "Enterprise Pack is there"
}
else{
    write-output "No Enterprise Pack"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like it'll do the job although since posting I had a little experiment with a try-catch block and managed to get it working as required. I'm just testing further and will post when the code when done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the following does what I want also. Because the -LicenseOptions parameter isn't terminating and doesn't produce an error even if the service is already enabled it means I can run this after the initial script block which uses the -AddLicenses parameter. Also with this method I'm configuring the services in only one place although not hard to implement in the if-else statement above.

```
            Try
        {
            Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $Upn -AddLicenses tenent:ENTERPRISEPACK -ErrorAction Stop
            "$(Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss):  $($Upn): Office 365 Enterprise E3 Product License enabled" | Tee-Object $UserMigrationLog -Append
        }
        Catch
        {
            "$(Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss):  $($Upn): Office 365 Enterprise E3 Product License already assigned" | Tee-Object $UserMigrationLog -Append
        }
        #Present so specific configurations can be set if required
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $Upn -LicenseOptions $O365EntE3
        "$(Get-Date -f HH:mm:ss):  $($Upn): Office 365 Enterprise E3 configured services enabled" | Tee-Object $UserMigrationLog -Append
```

Thanks again though and will keep yours in mind for future reference.